# Make synchronous request inside Cypres.config.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, cypress

I am using Cypress 12.13.0 and I am trying to use the hooks that execute stuff before the test session starts. I need to perform some actions before any test and any spec file. According to cypress documentation, the right place to do this is at the `cypress.config.ts` file.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on): void {
            on('before:run', () => {
                // Stuff here will be executed at the beginning of the Cypress session
                console.log('foo');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

That works as I expected. But now I want to execute a request synchronously after `console.log('foo');`. I am not finding an easy way to do this because most of the functions rely on `async` methods. I could get this one though but still the end result is async:

```
function performRequest() {
    axios
        .get(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error.message);
        });
}
```

Another approach is to use a shell script before the Cypress session to perform the same stuff I need but that solution does not feel very professional.

Comment: The first line of [the usage docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api#Usage) says that you can return a Promise and it will be awaited before proceeding.

Comment: That refers to the return value of the 'before:run' callback, not the `performRequest()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the `before:run` callback `async`, then use `await`.

```js
function performRequest() {
    return axios                              // return the implicit promise here
        .get(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error.message);
        });
}

import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on): void {
            on('before:run', async () => {           // make this function async

                const data = await performRequest()  // await synchronously

            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I lettile correction, I had to change `performRequest` in the next way to it work:

`async function performRequest(): Promise<any> {
        try {
          const response: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(apiUrl);
          console.log("LOOKING GOOOD")
          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
          throw error;
        }
    }`